# Neo4j spatial server plugin fails on withinDistance and closest java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I know that the plugin is being loaded properly, as other methods work such as spatial.procedures and spatial.addNode etc.

The error results after a call like this:

```
CALL spatial.withinDistance('profile_geo', [43.524, 96.7341], 500)
```

and the error that results is this:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `spatial.withinDistance`: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_0/commands/expressions/GeographicPoint
```

The same error appears when trying to use the closest function as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j Spatial are you running with which version of Neo4j?

Comment: neo4j-community-3.0.2 and neo4j-spatial-0.17-neo4j-3.0.2-server-plugin.jar

Comment: I am encountering the same problem when using CYPHER and have tried neo4j-spatial v0.16 and v0.17 (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837663/neo4j-spatial-3-0-2-no-index-provider-spatial-found first comment under the answer of @Michael Hunger). When using the REST path, it works: `'/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance'`. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are missing required Jar for GeographicalPoint class.
Please make sure you have this class in your Jars. I know this class exists in *neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0-3.0.3.jar* but it is not going to work for you as it is residing in different namespace. If you will not be able to pinpoint the corresponding Jar in your environment please have a look at Maven repository and try to find it there.

Comment: The server plugin is a precompiled extension, shouldn't this class already be compiled into the extension?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: upgrade to 3.0.3 (both neo4j and plugin)

long answer:

I ran into the exact same issue today. I was running version 3.0.2 with server plugin version 3.0.2 and ran the cypher query:

```
 CALL spatial.withinDistance("spatial_records",{lon:20.0,lat:50.0},100000000)
```

Joran mentioned in the comments above that the REST API was a working alternative. So I tried that out and found he was indeed correct.

I tested this using httpie, with the following command:

```
cat tmp.json | http :7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance
```

where tmp.json looks like:

```
{"layer" : "spatial_records","pointX" :3.9706,"pointY" : 46.7907,"distanceInKm" :10000000000}
```

While this works, using CYPHER with stored procedures would be nice. So upon further investigation, I noticed that a recent [commit](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/commit/178b0efda3e607ae2ffcad353688c8aa43176d06) contained the following changes:

```
-        <neo4j.version>3.0.1</neo4j.version>
+        <neo4j.version>3.0.3</neo4j.version>

...

-import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_0.commands.expressions.GeographicPoint;
+import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_0.GeographicPoint;
```

So I ended up downloading version 3.0.3 of both neo4j and the spatial plugin. Whatever the issue was before, seems to be fixed in this version. The call to the stored procedure now works as expected!