# Neo4j Spatial 3.0.2: No index provider 'spatial' found

Tags: php, curl, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am trying to create a spatial database with neo4j 3.0.2 and neo4j-spatial for 3.0.2. I have installed the plugin and I have checked that the plugin is running with cURL `curl -v http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474/db/data/` which outputs following:

```
{
  "extensions" : {
    "SpatialPlugin" : {
      "addSimplePointLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer",
      "addNodesToLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodesToLayer",
      "findClosestGeometries" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findClosestGeometries",
      "addGeometryWKTToLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addGeometryWKTToLayer",
      "findGeometriesWithinDistance" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance",
      "addEditableLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addEditableLayer",
      "addCQLDynamicLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addCQLDynamicLayer",
      "addNodeToLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer",
      "getLayer" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/getLayer",
      "findGeometriesInBBox" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesInBBox",
      "updateGeometryFromWKT" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/updateGeometryFromWKT",
      "findGeometriesIntersectingBBox" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesIntersectingBBox"
    }
  },
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
  "relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship",
  "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "indexes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index",
  "constraints" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
  "transaction" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
  "node_labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels",
  "neo4j_version" : "3.0.2"
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}* Closing connection #0
```

Now I can create a new simplePointLayer:

```
// define entity manager
$client = $this->get('neo4j.spatial_manager')->getClient();



// 1. Create a pointlayer
$request = $client->request('POST',
    '/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer',
    [
        'json' => [
            'layer' => 'geom',
            'lat' => 'lat',
            'lon' => 'lon',
        ],
    ]
);

var_dump($request);
```

This creates the spatial root node with the rTree. But when I now want to create a spatial index with following:

```
// 2. Create a spatial index
$request = $client->request('POST',
    '/db/data/index/node/',
    [
        'json' => [
            'name' => 'geom',
            'config' => [
                'provider' => 'spatial',
                'geometry_type' => 'point',
                'lat' => 'lat',
                'lon' => 'lon',
            ],
        ],
    ]
);

var_dump($request);
```

I am confronted with the error-message:

```
"message" : "No index provider 'spatial' found.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have checked a lot of forums and so on, but the answer always seems to be to install the spatial plugin, which I have and it seems to be working according to the first output.

**EDIT 15.06.2016**

Whats weird is that I can add nodes to the rTree:

```
   // Create a node with spatial data
    $json = [
        'team' => 'REDBLUE',
        'name' => 'TEST',
        'lat' => 25.121075,
        'lon' => 89.990630,
    ];
    $response = $client->request('POST',
        '/db/data/node', 
        [
            'json' => $json
        ]
    );

    $node = json_decode($response->getBody(), true)['self'];

   // Add the node to the layer
   $response = $client->request('POST',
        '/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer',
        [
            'json' => [
                'layer' => 'geom',
                'node' => $node,
            ],
        ]
    );

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    var_dump($data);
```

And I can query the nodes through REST:

```
    $request = $client->request('POST',
        '/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance',
        [
            'json' => [
                'layer' => 'geom',
                'pointX' => 89.99506,
                'pointY' => 25.121260,
                'distanceInKm' => 10,
            ],
        ]
    );

$data = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);

var_dump($data);
```

But why is it not letting me create an index? Or does it do the indexing automatically? And if so, how can I query using CYPHER (in the web console for example)?

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index provider was removed (back then it was the only means to provide integration with Cypher), in favor of user defined procedures for Spatial.

see: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/procedures/SpatialProceduresTest.java#L113

As this is a new major release (for 3.0) we found it sensible to remove the index provider.

Comment: Thanks for this vital piece of information! So how exactly do I do spatial queries with Cypher? If I try `CALL spatial.withinDistance('geom',{pointX:89.99506,pointY:25.121260},100)` I get the error: `Failed to invoke procedure `spatial.withinDistance`: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_0/commands/expressions/GeographicPoint`

Comment: The same error also comes up when creating everything with the call commands using the defaults: `CALL spatial.addPointLayer('geom')` then `create (n:Tile{name:'`test',latitude:47.99,longitude:7.886})` and finally: `match (t:Tile) with t call spatial.addNode('geom',t) YIELD node return count(*)`. If I then query using: `CALL spatial.withinDistance('geom',{latitude:47.60,longitude:7.7},100)` the same error appears.